# Using AJAX to contact php. AJAX is not acting as if it is getting a response

Tags: php, ajax

Everything seems to work except the code within the if statement brackets.

In other words Ajax is acting as if it's not getting a response from the server.

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
          document.body.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://someaddress.com/interface.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("name=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

Comment: can you alert and see what's the status?

Comment: What does your browser's JavaScript console say? Are there any errors? What does your browser's develop tools Net tab say? Is the request being made? Does it look as you expect? What about the response? If you try to log them, what values to readyState and status actually have?

Comment: I checked, and the response status is 0. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. The problem was server-sided. I needed to allow access from external applications in the PHP, like so:

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");